# How to read images for nib.load() function so they can be resized?

Tags: python, png, glob, dicom, nib

Trying to design a FCNN for kidney segmentation for MR images. Have 40 images (DICOM) and their associated ground truth labels (PNG) mounted to the Google Drive for the Colab notebook that I am building the architecture upon.

For these 40 images and their labels, trying to resize all of them to 256 x 256 using the code below (and it is practically a carbon copy for the label resizing). Receiving a "list index out of range" for both blocks of code but I am aware of the "n-1" rule for the range() call, so it has to be the glob block of code that is listed just below.

---

```
from glob import glob
img_path = glob.glob("/content/drive/My Drive/CHOAS_Kidney_Labels/Training_Images/IMG*.dcm")
mask_path = glob.glob("/content/drive/My Drive/CHOAS_Kidney_Labels/Ground_Truth_Training/IMG*.png")
```

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'glob'
```

---

```
images=[]
a=[]
for i in range(0,39):
    a=nib.load(img_path[i])
    a=a.get_data()
    print("image (%d) loaded"%(i))
    a=resize(a,(a.shape[0],256,256))
    a=a[:,:,:]
    for j in range(a.shape[0]):
        images.append((a[j,:,:]))
```

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you used `from glob import glob`, you don't need the `glob.glob`.  You should just call `glob` without the namespace glob.

Your second error is because `img_path` is empty.  And you're better off doing something like:

```
for name in img_path:
    a=nib.load(name)
```

Comment: Tried the modification but received a "ImageFileError: cannot work out file type of '/content/drive/My Drive/Images/IMG-0004-00040.dcm'".